# UIWebView video should fill the frame size mentioned

Tags: ios, video, uiwebview, frame

I am using uiwebview to display inline video using the following code :

```
UIWebView *webview =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 320)];
[webview setOpaque:NO];
webview.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

NSString *Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<video controls id='myVideo' width='%fpx' height='%fpx' float:left webkit-playsinline preload=\"auto\"> <source src=\"%@\"> </video>",webview.frame.size.width,webview.frame.size.height,videoPath];
[webview loadHTMLString:Str baseURL:nil];
webview.allowsInlineMediaPlayback=YES;
webview.scrollView.scrollEnabled = NO;
webview.mediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction=NO;
[self addSubview:webview];
```

Video is playing inline, but the problem is video is getting displayed in rectangle and there is a black space on either side of the video please find attached image

[image]

Can anyone suggest me what is going wrong here, i need to display the video in full size (provide frame size) so that there is no spacing on either side.

Comment: i thinks it is nothing to do with UIWebView, as HTML code is adding blackColor to the div.

Comment: How can i overcome it? i need to show video to fit the frame size